# I got blank page in openshift

Tags: openshift

URL: http://role-baaptechnologies.rhcloud.com/Role

Deployed war file to openshift

```
1) removed the src/pom.xml file
2) added war to the webapps dir
3) did git add/commit/push
```

But I am getting blank page.

Comment: What is name of the war file? Does it contain index.html or index.jsp

Comment: Name of the war file is Role. It contains Role.html

Comment: Does this work locally? What URL you use on your local machine? Have you checked the logs file by running rhc tail command?

Comment: Yes. It works locally. http://localhost:8080/Role........==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
Apr 28, 2014 10:51:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Role] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 28, 2014 10:51:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc

Comment: Can you update the question with error you are seeing in log file?

Comment: SEVERE: The web application [/Role] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.Apr 28, 2014 10:51:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start. INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.11.250.129-8080"].Apr 28, 2014 10:51:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start. INFO: Server startup in 86119 ms

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application deployed at the root context, then you need to name it ROOT.war, otherwise it would be located at http://app-domain.rhcloud.com/Role

Comment: What url are you trying to visit it at?

Comment: app:role,domain:baaptechnologies, war name:Role            http://role-baaptechnologies.rhcloud.com/Role

Comment: Looks like it's not failing, so it is deployed correctly it would seem.  Do you have content on that index page?